# A question regarding sale of items in smritis and scriptures?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, smriti, vaishya

Pranam
Is it necessary for seller and buyer to be present at the place of selling to take place?
Is mental selling(via manasika sankalpa not verbal) valid?
What happens if an object is sold but isnt delivered by the seller?
Is the sale valid if the seller was intoxicated or mentally unsound?
Kindly quote scriptural references
Thanks